# Work around INSERT race condition mysql, avoiding locks

Tags: mysql, innodb

Suppose I have a couple of scripts sending (legitimate!) emails. Each script handles a part of a bigger list, and they run concurrently. Before sending, every address has to be checked to avoid sending to the same address twice.

To do this, I created a simple table (mysql 5.1, innodb) with just the email-address. If it's not in the table, then add it, and send the mail. Now I need to avoid the race condition where multiple scripts test the same address at the same time and erroneously conclude it's not been sent to. I guess I can use locks for this, but I'd rather not do that because of performance reasons.

So I'd like to know if the following alternative is correct:

- adding a unique index on the address column
- just insert the address, without checking by selecting
- trap the mysql error code returned: if it's 1062, the address already existed.

In this setup, is there still a possibility for a race condition? I mean: is it still possible that two scripts that insert an address at almost the same time both conclude that the mail has not been sent? Or should I use locks for this?

Thanks,
Stijn

Comment: Out of interest, why not just use 1 script?

Comment: Where do those e-mails come from? Is it an issue if the script crashes before e-mail is actually sent? What makes you think that locks do not work properly? (Other than that, unique indexes are a valid way to avoid dupes.)

Comment: @F4r-20: to enable multiple concurrent connections to postfix servers.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: it's a big list, and to speed up sending, it's split in multiple smaller lists. The script should not crash. Locks work but seem overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I feel the database isn’t the best place for this.  While your bigger list is sending out email (I’m guessing on a very large scale due to your attempt at paralysation) you must be using a temporary table given that you wouldn’t want to restrict sending of a different email to a recipient of a previous mailing.

A cache would be the obvious choice here maintaining a list of addresses, or a server acting as a shared memory resource.

However you could do it in the database, and from my understanding it isn’t really vital if one email address exists more than once as all you’re doing is checking one hasn’t been sent to that in the past.  You can’t really control the race condition of multiple scripts sending to the same address at the same time without a locking policy.  You could however make it more efficient by using an index.  I wouldn’t index the actual address but create a new column with a CRC32 hash of the address (which can be a 32bit unsigned integer which only takes 4 bytes of memory).  Using the CRC32 approach you will also have to check the email address in the query due to the birthday paradox.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM email_addresses
WHERE email_address_crc = CRC32(?address)
AND email_address = ?address
```

Having something which is efficient should help against race conditions however as I’ve said before the only way to guarantee it is to lock the database while each email is being sent so you can then maintain an exact list – this unfortunately doesn’t scale and would mean having parallel tasks sending email would probably not help.

**Edit in response to comments below:**

As pointed out in the comments I actually forgot to address svdr’s alternative to a locking solution.  It is true that a unique index containing the email address (or a composite index containing the campaign ID and address) would indeed throw a MySQL exception if the address exists and thus resulting in a working solution with parallel scripts sending to the same address at the same time. However, it is very hard to handle any exceptions such as not sending the email due to SMTP errors / network issues when the address is entered before the script ‘try’s’ to send an email, this could result in a recipient not receiving an email.  Also providing this is a very simple INSERT and SELECT it should be fine just to trap the MySQL exception, however if there is anything more complex such as wrapping commands in transactions or using SELECT FOR UPDATE etc this can result in a deadlock situation.

Another couple of considerations are, the email address field would need to be fully indexed for performance reasons, if using INNODB this limit is 767 bytes – given the maximum valid length of an email address is 254 (+1 byte for length if using VARCHAR) you should be fine providing you don’t have some huge primary key.

Index performance should be addressed too, and CHAR vs VCHAR should be evaluated.  Index lookups on a CHAR field are usually between 15% - 25% faster than the equivalent VCHAR lookup – fixed width table sizes can also help depending on the table engine used.

To summarise, yes your non-locking solution would work but should be tested and evaluated carefully with your exact requirements (I cannot comment on specifics as I would assume your real life scenario is more complex than your SO question).  As stated in the first line of the answer I still believe the database isn't the best place for this and a cache or shared memory space would be more efficient and easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks! We need persistence, because a campaign may be resent to added recipients and we need the check again. Good idea to use a hash as an index. About my alternative to locking: can you explain why that would not work?

Comment: @svdr I will edit my answer - I got carried away with another approach I totally forgot to address that point!

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I will do some testing to find the optimal solution. And I'll upvote your answer as soon as I hit 15 reputation ;)